# Java jar file command line parameters

Tags: java, jar

What are the parameters i can append to a standard "java -jar " command? For example this is one:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar
```

The "-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M" bascially gives it 1024mb of RAM right? What else can i put in the command?

Comment: This information is widely available with a simple Google search. Did you try using Google?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
java -help
```

This will give you a list of all available options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) i found that was helpful.